# Pin based 'oauth for devices' not enable for google plus

Tags: google-oauth

It seems that some services aren't supporting 'oauth for devices' (pin-based oauth). This is a bit of a big deal for those of us who work at the command-line console.

However, some very important google scopes, like gdrive and google-plus, don't seem to. For example:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

doesn't work. It returns 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request' and the JSON error 'invalid scope: not authorized to request the scopes'

I'd include more scopes, but stack overflow says I need +10 reputation to post links.

Is pin-based oauth disabled for services like blogger, gdrive and google-plus, or do I have the wrong scopes?

regards,

Colum

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the scopes you describe are not currently enabled for OAuth2 for devices (PIN-based OAuth).

Answer (score 0):

As breno answered, only a part of the scopes are supported by OAuth2.0 for devices with limited input capabilities.

The followings is my result with YouTube Data API v3 scopes (as of July, 2014).
I share it so that other people can find this Q&A more easily and escape from the trap.

```
Works:
  auth/youtube

Fails with "Bad Request(400)"
  auth/youtube.readonly
  auth/youtube.upload
  auth/youtubepartner
  auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit
```

This question and breno's answer saved me from searching in vain for the cause of the problem. Thanks.